# How to design DynamoDB for news articles table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to DynamoDB. Actually I'm looking for a replacement for my Parse database, and end up looking at Amazon Mobile Hub. However, after trying out DynamoDB, I can't get my head around how to design a database that can query for example 10 latest news article. Let's say my Article table is very simple, with just title and content. How do I do this without expensively scan the whole table ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb can order your results only by the range key value, so in your example, range key need to be created_ts. (make it integer timestamp).
now, the problem is to get a good hash key (that will spread equally - to prevent throughput errors). i dont know your specific flow, but this is what you need to resolve (what will be your hash key)

please read the next article, it will help you to figure your use case,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html

Comment: Thanks man. I'm used to the auto increment primary key of MySQL. Can you suggest one good hash key in my case ? And is querying to get 10 latest item ordered by created_ts expensive in DynamoDB ?